# MyBatis SQL transactions with Struts 2

Tags: sql, struts2, transactions, dao, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis with Struts 2 and I'm curious about setting up custom sessions. I will explain more below.

Currently I have a bunch of DAOs which open a session, execute their query, commit if necessary, and close their connection:

```
public String selectUsername(Integer id){
    session = getSession();                         //opens the session
    mapper = session.getMapper(UserMapper.class);   //gets the mapper

    String name = mapper.selectUsername(id);        //executes query
    session.close();                                //closes session

    return name;
}
```

Sometimes I have complex things I need to do such as inserting a large object which consists of smaller objects which each have their own DAO:

```
public boolean insertNewProfile(UserProfile profile)
{
    session = getSession();
    mapper = session.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    int result = mapper.insertNewProfile(profile);
    session.commit();

    int id = mapper.selectId(profile.getUserName());
    for(UserSkill skill : profile.getSkills())
        skill.setUserID(id);        

    // insert the user's skills in the database
    boolean skillResult = skillDAO.insertSkills(profile.getSkills());

    session.close();

    return (result > 0) && skillResult;
}
```

In the above, you can see that we are not only inserting the `UserProfile`, but we are also inserting the associated `UserSkill`s by using the `UserSkillDAO`. That DAO also opens the session, commits, and closes the session. I'm trying to make this compound query to the database in **one session**.

I have tried making functions to open, commit, and close the session at the action level (Struts 2) but when I tried that I get errors (`### Error querying database. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Executor was closed. ### The error may exist in . . .`) about the session being closed prematurely to my closing it. I have looked into using MyBatis transactions but a lot of the examples online are for older versions of iBatis or are examples using Spring.

Example of opening/closing sessions at the action level:

```
public String execute(){
    DAOFactory.openSession();

    logger.info("Creating ProjectDAO");
    projectDAO = DAOFactory.getDao(ProjectDAO.class);
    needDAO = DAOFactory.getDao(ProjectNeedDAO.class);
    majorDAO = DAOFactory.getDao(ProjectNeedMajorsDAO.class);
    skillDAO = DAOFactory.getDao(ProjectNeedSkillDAO.class);

    logger.info("Performing selectAllProjects query.");
    projects = projectDAO.selectAllProjects();


    // loop over the projects and add the project needs
    for(int i = 0; i < projects.size(); i++){



        // get all of the project needs for a project
        projects.get(i).setProjectNeeds((ArrayList<ProjectNeed>)needDAO.selectProjectNeeds(projects.get(i).getProjectID()));

        // loop over all of the project needs and add the majors and skills needed
        for(int j = 0; j < projects.get(i).getProjectNeeds().size(); j++){
            ArrayList<ProjectNeed> needs = projects.get(i).getProjectNeeds();

            needs.get(j).setMajors((ArrayList<ProjectNeedMajor>)majorDAO.selectProjectNeedMajors(needs.get(j).getNeedID()));
            needs.get(j).setSkills((ArrayList<ProjectNeedSkill>)skillDAO.selectProjectNeedSkills(needs.get(j).getNeedID()));
        }
    }

    DAOFactory.closeSession();

    logger.info("Returning success");
    return "success";
}
```

Is there an easy way for me to rework my code so that I can choose when to open and close sessions at the action level instead of at the DAO level as I believe the opening and closing of sessions involves a lot of overhead and is slowing down the performance of my website?

Comment: You need to provide more information. When do you get the message about prematurely-closed sessions? Are you trying to load data lazily in the view (IMO a bad idea anyway)? Is there an existing filter or interceptor *also* trying to close the session?

Comment: Hi Dave. It seemed to be very spastic; giving me the error whenever I tried to do something in the system. My output was littered with this error and I was forced to revert my changes before I had a chance to pinpoint exact times at which it errored. I have not added any special interceptors that try to close the session. I'll try to pull an old revision to track down when the error is occurring but iirc it happened pretty much with every query.

Comment: Upon retrieving the old revision, I am noticing that the error sometimes occurs during some actions but it sometimes does not. However with other actions, it always occurs. Actions shouldn't be calling other actions so the session should not be prematurely closing...

Comment: Define "during actions". I still strongly suspect lazy loading in the view. If it's happening in the *middle* of actions then you need to determine what else is accessing the session afterwards. So far I suspect issues with your DAO implementation. Another thing that would have helped is properly separating concerns: there is *far* too much happening your actions; access across DAOs should be moved into services, and transaction management should be handled by Spring or the equivalent--it handles so much of this for you.

Comment: The view is handled by the struts 2 framework. We load the page using jsp's which are called up by the actions returning `success`. What I mean by "during actions" is that when I want to load all the projects in the database, I am always getting this error. When I want to view my profile, I only sometimes get this error. It's always executing the same code but sometimes I get this exception. As far as using the framework for transactions, I've looked into this but haven't found a good example.

Comment: If you want to use S2 for TX management you want an interceptor that wraps action and view rendering. Without knowing anything about how your DAOFactory (and possible the DAOs) are implemented it's impossible to help. Is your DAOFactory thread-safe? What does the "session close" code actually *do* in your DAOs if not close a session?

Comment: I showed you an example of a DAO and that's pretty much how all of the DAO's work. As far as the DAOFactory is concerned, it sets up the `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder` and connection information for the database. Opening a session is as simple as calling `openSession()` on the `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder`. Closing a session is just calling `session.close()` on the session. I'm going to feel really dumb if this is a threading issue although only one action should be happening at once.. The current session is a static variable that is returned when an action calls `getSession()`.

Comment: How do you figure that only one action should be happening at once?

Comment: If I interact with the website in any way, it calls an action on the server side. I can't be in a different action since I haven't been served up a new jsp to interact with yet.

Comment: Well, it's a website, so it's entirely possible that more than one person will use it at once, no? Also, if you have multiple tabs open or otherwise initiate multiple requests, your assumption will not hold true. Nevertheless, holding the session in a static variable that can be easily wiped out by another incoming request will guarantee that you will have problems later, if it's not part of the problem now.

Comment: I've pondered over your thoughts, Steven, and I suppose I assumed that the struts 2 framework would have handled all of the threading for me... This now seems like a stupid thought but it was had nonetheless. If indeed threading is causing my issue and it is handled through transactions that are supported by the framework, could one of you gents possibly provide an example I could reference or somewhere I can go to learn more about transactions with struts2? I'm guessing I'll need to refactor a lot of my code which will be rather tedious but beneficial in the long run.

Comment: @user2607126 Struts knows *nothing* about *your* static variables. If you have a static variable in a class that *you're* handling... I'm really not sure what led you to believe it would be anything but a wreck when multiple people were using it. S2 knows *nothing* about transactions; it's a web framework, and data-agnostic.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, Dave. I already had this epiphany. Your comment isn't constructive.

Comment: @user2607126 Neither is that one; big deal. Sorry for helping; won't happen again.

Comment: @user2607126 As Dave indicated, you can use an interceptor which will open the session and then close it, wrapping the invocation of the action and the rendering of the view. You'll probably want to refactor your code first though to resolve the issue of the session being in a static variable. You may also want to consider a dependency injection approach to your code. It would make it a lot more testable.

Comment: @user2607126 Opening and closing a session is not much expensive as opening and closing a connection and it can't involve much overhead if you implement a session per thread pattern.